# modalInstance injuctor error in angular js

Tags: angularjs

```
MyAdmin.controller('AdminMasterController', ['$rootScope', '$q', '$scope', '$http', 'ApiCall', 'DTOptionsBuilder', 'DTColumnDefBuilder', '$window', 'myStorageService', '$ocLazyLoad', '$modal','$modalInstance',
function ($rootScope, $q, $scope, $http, ApiCall, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnDefBuilder, $window, myStorageService, $ocLazyLoad, $modal,$modalInstance) 
{
  $scope.btnViewClick = function (job) {
    myStorageService.setMyStorage('empCode', job.EmployerCode);

    $ocLazyLoad.load({
        name: 'MyAdmin',
        files: ['MyAdmin/angular_scripts/controllers/viewPopUpController.js'

        ]
    }).then(function () {


        $scope.modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'MyAdmin/angular_views/DetailsPopup/viewpopup.html',
            controller: 'viewPopUpController',
            size: 'sm'
        });


    });

}


$scope.closeModal = function () {
    $modalInstance.close();
}


}]);
```

Here I inject modalInstance but when page load it give me modalInstance Error

Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/unpr?p0=%24modalInstanceProvider%20%3C-%20%24modalInstance%20%3C-%20AdminMasterController

Answer (score 0):

With the latest Bootstrap UI these two dependencies are called `$uibModal` and `$uibModalInstance`.

[Docs can be found here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/modal)

---

Also, there is no need to inject the `$uibModalInstance` into your controller, since you have created your own modal instance here:

```
$scope.modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'MyAdmin/angular_views/DetailsPopup/viewpopup.html',
    controller: 'viewPopUpController',
    size: 'sm'
});
```

Because you now have `$scope.modalInstance` available, you should be able to close it with:

```
$scope.closeModal = function () {
    $scope.modalInstance.close();
}
```

Comment: Then maybe you're not using the latest version of Bootstrap UI. Just remove `$modalInstance` from your dependencies, and rename all references to `$modalInstance` in your code to `$scope.modalInstance`, and you should be fine.